# Como pegar o valor vinculado a um selectOneRadio e atribuí-lo a um atributo em um Bean

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces, jpa

Solicito ajuda para implementar um método/maneira de pegar o valor vinculado a um selectOneRadio (que é um Enum) e atribuí-lo a um atributo dentro de um Bean.

Após obter o valor vinculado ao selectOneRadio, vou passá-lo como parâmetro para um método chamado newPessoa e assim instanciar um atributo do tipo Pessoa localizado em uma classe Cliente.

Estou estudanto e paralelamente desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java EE utilizando JSF, PrimeFaces e JPA.
O foco principal do aprendizado é a utilização de Herança com JPA(consequentemente a herança do Java) e também Composição.
Optei por utilizar a estratégia de herança JOINED, por entender que desta forma as tabelas da base de dados ficam mais normalizadas.
Diante disso, implementei 4 classes:

Pessoa (abstrata)
PessoaFisica (herda de Pessoa)
PessoaJuridica (herda de Pessoa)
Cliente (possui um atributo de Pessoa, uma vez que pode ser tanto PessoaFisica ou PessoaJuridica)

A princípio defini na classe Pessoa um atributo tipoDePessa, que é um enum composto por FISICA e JURIDICA, onde a ideia é: vincular os valores deste enum a um "p:selectOneRadio" para que dependendo do tipo que for selecionado (FISICO ou JURIDICO) instanciar o objeto Pessoa como PessoaFisica ou PessoaJuridica.

Para isso, implementei também uma classe (utilizando o Design Patterns de Criação Factory Method) PessoaFactoty. Esta classe possui o método newPessoa que recebe como parâmetro um PessoaType e dependendo do tipo (FISICA ou JURIDICA) um tipo de pessoa é instanciado.

Abaixo consta a imagem de um diagrama de classes para demonstra o cenário do relacionamento entre as classes citadas.
Abaixo também estão os códigos referentes à implementação das classes.

PS: Após concluir esta parte da implementação, quero desenvolver uma forma para que assim que a página for reinderizada, a opção FISICA já esteja selecionada, tipo este vai ser o tipo de pessoa default, e também vai haver um formulário para cada tipo de pessoa, se for selecionado FISICA, haverá campos de CPF, RG, etc, caso seja JURIDICA, haverá os campos CNPJ, Insc. Estadual, etc., ou seja, o formulário será dinâmico.

Desde já agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOAS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PESS_TIPO")
public abstract class Pessoa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PESS_CODIGO", nullable = false)
private Integer codigo;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "PESS_TIPO_DE_PESSOA")
private PessoaType tipoDePessoa;

@Column(name = "PESS_NOME", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(name = "PESS_FONE", length = 20, nullable = false)
private String telefone;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pessoa")
private Endereco endereco;

@Column(name = "PESS_OBSERVACAO", length = 255, nullable = true)
private String observacao;

@Column(name = "PESS_STATUS", length = 1, nullable = false)
private Boolean status;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "PESS_DATA_CADASTRO", nullable = false)
private Date dataCadastro;

@Version
@Column(name = "PESS_DATA_ALTERACAO", nullable = false)
private Timestamp dataAlteracao;

protected Pessoa() {

}
// Gets e Sets
```

Pessoa Física

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOA_FISICA")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PF")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PESS_CODIGO")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "PESF_CPF", length = 14, nullable = false)
private String cpf;

@Column(name = "PESF_RG", length = 14, nullable = false)
private String rg;

@Column(name = "PESF_ORGAO_EMISSOR_RG", length = 20, nullable = false)
private String orgaoEmissorRg;

@Column(name = "PESF_EMAIL", length = 65, nullable = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "PESF_CELULAR", length = 14, nullable = true)
private String celular;

@Lob
@Column(name = "PESF_FOTO", nullable = true)
private byte[] foto;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "PESF_DATA_NASCIMENTO", nullable = false)
private Date dataNascimento;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "PESF_SEXO", nullable = false)
private SexoType sexo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente")
private List<PedidoVenda> pedidos;

public PessoaFisica() {

}
```

Pessoa Jurídica

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOA_JURIDICA")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PJ")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PESS_CODIGO")
public class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "PESJ_NOME_FANTASIA", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String nomeFantasia;

@Column(name = "PESJ_CNPJ", length = 14, nullable = false)
private String cnpj;

@Column(name = "PESJ_INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL", length = 15, nullable = false)
private String inscricaoEstadual;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "PESJ_VALIDADE_INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL", nullable = false)
private Date validadeInscricaoEstadual;

@Column(name = "PESJ_INSCRICAO_MUNICIPAL", length = 15, nullable = true)
private String inscricaoMunicipal;

@Column(name = "PESJ_HOME_PAGE", length = 100, nullable = true)
private String homePage;

@Column(name = "PESJ_FAX", length = 15, nullable = true)
private String fax;

public PessoaJuridica() {

}
```

Classe Factory para instanciar uma pessoa de acordo com o tipo passado por parâmetro.

```
public class PessoaFactory {
public static Pessoa newPessoa(PessoaType tipo) {
    if (tipo == PessoaType.FISICA) {
        return new PessoaFisica();
    } else if (tipo == PessoaType.JURIDICA) {
        return new PessoaJuridica();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Bean

```
@Named(value = "clienteBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ClienteBean extends Bean {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private ClienteService clienteService;

private Cliente cliente;

private Pessoa pessoa;

private Cliente clienteSelecionado;

private List<Cliente> clientes;

public void instanciarPessoa(ValueChangeEvent event) {

    HtmlSelectOneRadio radio = (HtmlSelectOneRadio) event.getComponent();
    PessoaType tipo = (PessoaType) radio.getValue();

    System.out.println(tipo);
}

public List<PessoaType> getTiposDePessoa() {
    return Arrays.asList(PessoaType.values());
}

public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
    try {
        if (clientes == null) {
            clientes = clienteService.listarTodosClientes();
        }
        return clientes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
        return null;
    }
}

public String novoCliente() {
    cliente = new Cliente();
    return redirect(Outcome.CADASTRO_CLIENTE);
}
}
```

Parte do arquivo XHTML

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputLabel value="Tipo de Pessoa" for="tipoPessoa" />
        <p:selectOneRadio 
            id="tipoPessoa" 
            value="#{clienteBean.pessoa.tipoDePessoa}" 
            valueChangeListener="#{clienteBean.instanciarPessoa}">
            <f:selectItems 
                value="#{clienteBean.tiposDePessoa}" 
                var="tipoDePessoa" 
                itemValue="tipoDePessoa"
                itemLabel="#{tipoDePessoa.descricao}">
            </f:selectItems>
        </p:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do princípio de que você já possui seu ManagerBean para controlar o sistema de cadastro, vou supor que o nome do seu Bean seja CadastroPessoaBean, nele você deverá ter um método get como segue:

```
 //
 private Pessoa pessoa;
 //Pega o tipo de pessoa que foi selecionada
 public Pessoa getPessoa() {
    return pessoa;
 }
 //Pega os valores de pessoas para exibir na página
 public TipoPessoa[] getTiposPessoas() {
    return TipoPessoa.values();
 }
```

Na página de cadastro você deverá referenciar o método da forma abaixo.

```
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid">
            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipo" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="tipo" 
                    value="#{CadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.tipoDePessoa}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#CadastroPessoaBean.tiposPessoas}"
                    var="tipoPessoa" itemValue="#{tipoPessoa}" 
                    itemLabel="#{tipoPessoa.descricao}" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

Enum:

```
public enum TipoPessoa {

  FISICA("Fisica"), 
  JURIDICA("Juridica");

  private String descricao;

  TipoPessoa(String descricao) {
      this.descricao = descricao;
  }

  public String getDescricao() {
      return descricao;
  }
}
```

## Editando...

Agora que já pegou o valor, você deve passá-lo para o seu Factory Method.

Algo dessa maneira...

```
public abstract class PessoaFactory{

    protected abstract TipoPessoaInterface newPessoa();
//Aqui vai criar o tipo de pessoa
    public void criacao(Pessoa tipo) {
        newPessoa().criar(tipo);
    }
}
```

Inteface da sua FactoryMethod

```
public interface TipoPessoaInterface {
    public Pessoa criar(Pessoa tipo);
}
```

Como vc está usando o FactoryMethod tem que ter as classes que serão responsáveis pela criação do objeto.
Depois vc pega esse objeto criado na classe Cliente para finalizar o seu cadastro.

Comment: Oi @Luiz as sugestões de implementação que você informou estão bem parecidas que as que eu já havia criado, exceto a implementação da classe PessoaFactory, pois criei algo mais simples (devido à falta de conhecimento).

Não consegui entender a última parte da sua resposta referente a classes responsáveis pela criação do objeto e depois pegar esse objeto criado na classe Cliente para finalizar o cadastro. Poderia me auxiliar um pouco mais? A dificuldade está na parte de pegar o valor selecionado no selectOneRadio e passar para a classe PessoaFactory, acho que devo usar um ValueChangeEvent.

Comment: Você pode usar o evento para decidir quais campos devem ser preenchidos, em um só formulário. Caso a pessoa marque física aí você pode habilitar os campos CPF e RG e deixar Hidden os campos de Jurídica. Aí você teria só um BackBean para controlar esse cadastro de Pessoa e TipoDePessoa..


Eu tinha pensado que vc poderia dividir o cadastro, no primeiro você pegaria o TipoPessoa e Pessoa e cadastrava no banco, depois chamava o segundo formulário de Cliente passando o id da pessoa que você cadastrou como parâmetro.

Comment: Na sua tabela Cliente teria uma Column de id_pessoa para você referenciar. E na table Pessoa já está referenciando o tipo pelo @Column(name = "PESS_TIPO_DE_PESSOA").

Pelo padrão do Factory Method você teria que ter uma classe de criação de objeto para cada tipo, eu acho um pouco complicado, mas é bem interessante no caso de você ter a possibilidade de adicionar mais tipos de pessoas no seu sistema, além de Jurídica e Física, se nunca for alterado, então não seria necessário.

Comment: Isso mesmo @Luiz, na minha classe Cliente há um atributo Pessoa (@JoinColumn(name = "PESS_CODIGO", nullable = false))

Na classe PessoaFactory o método newPessoa está assim:

    'public class PessoaFactory {
 public static Pessoa newPessoa(PessoaType tipo) {
  if (tipo == PessoaType.FISICA) {
   return new PessoaFisica();
  } else if (tipo == PessoaType.JURIDICA) {
   return new PessoaJuridica();
  } else {
   return null;
  }
 }
}

Comment: O que eu tinha tentado implementar no meu Bean para pegar o valor selecionado no selectOneRadio era um método assim: (desculpe, não consegui colocar o código formatado) public void instanciarPessoa(ValueChangeEvent event) { HtmlSelectOneRadio radio = (HtmlSelectOneRadio) event.getComponent(); PessoaType tipo = (PessoaType) radio.getValue(); System.out.println(tipo); }
mas não está dando certo pegar o valor, saberia me informar qual classe utilizar @Luiz, além da HtmlSelectOneRadio?